# Filling drop down lists with ajax from the same data table

Tags: php, mysql, jquery, drop-down-menu

I have a mysql database table with 5 columns.

> **id, columnA, columnB, columnC, columnD**

I filled datatable with these values so each column has 2 (distinct) values.

```
columnA 1, columnB 1, columnC 1, columnD 1
columnA 1, columnB 1, columnC 1, columnD 2
...
columnA 2, columnB 2, columnC 2, columnD 2
```

I want that user can select these values from drop-down lists. When he/she select the first data from columnA, the columnB values appear in the other select-box according to selected value. And so on.. So I guess I need to use ajax-jquery. Here is the script i've used,

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(
function() {
    $(".columnA").change(
    function() {
        var columnA=$(this).val();
        var dataString = 'columnA='+ columnA;
        $.ajax (    {
                        type: "POST",
                        url: "ajax_try.php",
                        data: dataString,
                        cache: false,
                        success: function(html)
                        {
                            $(".columnB").html(html);
                        }    
                    }               
                );

                }
        );
});
</script>
```

And the php codes.

```
<?php
    //index.php
    include('db.php');
    $sql=mysql_query("SELECT ID, columnA FROM try GROUP BY columnA");
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql))
    {
    $id = $row['id'];
    $columnA = $row['columnA'];
    echo '<option value="'.$id.'">'.$columnA.'</option>';
    } 
?>


<?php
   //ajax_try.php
   include('db.php');
   if($_POST['columnA'])
   {
      $columnA = $_POST['columnA'];
      $sql = mysql_query("SELECT ID, columnB from try WHERE columnA = '$columnA' GROUP BY columnB");

      while($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql))
      {
         $id = $row['id'];
         $columnB = $row['columnB'];
         echo '<option value="'.$id.'">'.$columnB.'</option>';
      }
   }
?>
```

I'm getting values of columnA but when I choose one of them, nothing happens. And I don't know how to bind other drop-down lists using ajax..

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest to best way to debug here is using following ways:

1) Alert on change to see whether function is being called or not

2) Debug php side using file_put_contents(..) and see what SQL actually gets executed?

3) Alert your data which you receive using Ajax to see whether you are receiving it or not?

If you debug right way using above 3 method, you should easily find what went wrong and where?

Good luck.